# DML operation in hibernate eventlistener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, event-listener, dml

here's a sample of what I need:

```
public class UserTransactionManager implements PreInsertEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener,
    ApplicationContextAware {

private static final long  serialVersionUID = -3535037001167635519L;
private static Log         log              = LogFactory.getLog(UserTransactionManager.class);

private ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof UserTransaction) {
        try {
            UserTransaction transaction = (UserTransaction) event.getEntity();
            log.debug("Pre update transaction action: " + transaction.getId());
            Integer index = Arrays.asList(event.getPersister().getPropertyNames()).indexOf(
                    "payed");
            if (!(Boolean) event.getOldState()[index] && (Boolean) event.getState()[index]) {
                AppUser user = (AppUser) event.getSession().load(AppUser.class,
                        transaction.getUser().getId());
                if (transaction.getType() == TransactionType.INCOMING) {
                    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + transaction.getValue());
                } else {
                    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() - transaction.getValue());
                }
                transaction.setBalance(user.getBalance());
                event.getSession().update(user);
            } else if ((Boolean) event.getOldState()[index]
                    && !(Boolean) event.getState()[index]) {
                AppUser user = (AppUser) event.getSession().load(AppUser.class,
                        transaction.getUser().getId());
                if (transaction.getType() == TransactionType.INCOMING) {
                    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() - transaction.getValue());
                } else {
                    user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + transaction.getValue());
                }
                transaction.setBalance(user.getBalance());
                event.getSession().update(user);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, the event is executed but I don't know how to update user entity from inside this list3ner.
`event.getSession().update(user);` doesn't work

Is there any way to do it?

Spring is managing my db sessions.

Spring - 3.1.0.RELEASE
Hibernate - 3.5.6-Final

Answer (score 0):

Don't save or update the object within listener and that's in not required. The Intention of listener is you to allowed modify the Entity object before saving. so the hibernate session will take care of changes present in the model that means you can freely modify the object fields.

Please ensure the return type should be true.
see the reference  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/PreInsertEventListener.html

```
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof UserTransaction) {

       try{

           ----------------
           -------------
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
             return false; // you already got exception so not required the partial changes in your entity. 
      }
```

Comment: Ok, so how can I update entity B when entity A is updated? Something like DB trigger, but from Spring or Hibernate?
Also in EventListener you return true if you want to rise a veto.